# Problems with Nexus 5 - everything stops working, even after fresh reinstall

Tags: crashes, 6.0-marshmallow

I had a problematic Nexus 5 - it constantly complains that [some app] has stopped (usually Google Play Services, but sometimes gapps or hangouts). It's usually Google Apps that crash.

I downgraded to Android 4.3, which helped a bit, but after a while started crashing randomly. After some thought I decided to try a fresh install. I installed stock Android 6, did a factory reset and cache wipe.

And it still complains all the time. The phone is goddamn unusable. What can I do???

Comment: have you tried doing factory reset on the stock recovery? Try doing that, and then flash again factory images.

Comment: @Paschalis what? what does "doing factory reset on the stock recovery" mean? I installed a stock version and then did a factory reset. What else?

Comment: are you using alternative recovery tool such as TWRP or CWM? if so, can you try flashing another rom just for testing?